# Pointer WPF control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

In Visual Studio 2010 Express, in the WPF toolbox there exists a `Pointer` control that cannot be dragged to the XAML window. Furthermore, trying the obvious `<Pointer />` XAML element shows that such an element does not exist. So what is the `Pointer` entry in the toolbox?

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Pointer isn't a control, it just means you can *select* controls with the mouse pointer.

Comment: This made me laugh a bit... sorry, I realize that people will think it's an actual control, but it still makes me laugh.

Comment: Thanks, I'm laughing now too. This is a real "any key" moment.

Comment: Hehe, couldn't really explain myself the purpose of that, as i usually drag controls it didn't bother me. But now i know. Good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* a little misleading, but as the comments pointed out, the "Pointer" item in those Controls lists is a placeholder for setting the visual editor into a selection state, so that you can move controls around or resize them on the design surface.